# MPLD3 not showing graph in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, mpld3

I'm using Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.11.4. Im trying to run [this](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/custom_plugin.html) example from the `mpld3` library. I read that `mpld3` does not work on python 3.5,

> The `mpld3` project is compatible with Python 2.6-2.7 and 3.3-3.4.

so I created a 3.4 environment using:

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

When running the script I get the following error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52484)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 305, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 331, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 673, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 401, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 389, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mpld3/_server.py", line 38, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write("<html><head>"
  File "/Users/Neill/anaconda/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 398, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I also made sure that the latest version of `mpld3` is installed. The local server then displays a blank page. Chrome's developer tools also report no errors. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?